# Internal Server error 500 when trying to present XML format as REST service response

Tags: java, xml, web-services, rest, cxf

This is regarding CXF REST service where in case of exception XML error tags will be the output.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "error")
public class ErrorXMLBean {

    private String code;
    private String description;

    public RestServiceErrorXMLBean(){
        this.code = "Sample Error code";
        this.description = "Sample Error Desc";
    }

    // some getters/setters
}
```

Constructing the Response with below code.

```
Response response = Response.status(200).type(MediaType.TEXT_XML).entity(new ErrorXMLBean()).build();
```

My resource method has below tag to tell to CXF that It will produce XML as response

```
@Produces({"text/xml"})
```

I am getting Internal Server `error 500`. Can someone point me where I am wrong?

(using cxf-2.2.5.jar)

Answer (score 3):

> I am getting Internal Server error 500. can someone point me where I am wrong?

Look in the server logs.  There is most likely a log event corresponding to the whatever caused the 500 error.

If you need more help, update your question with relevant details from the log event; e.g. the exception message and stack trace.